# C# - Asynchronous Text Reading Blocking

Tags: c#

My goal is to use StreamReader to read a text file asynchronously.
This is my code for reading the file content:

```
private async Task<string> PrintContent(string URL)
    {
             string result = string.Empty;
             using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(URL))
             {
                    result = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();
                    sr.Dispose();
             }
            return result;
      }
```

I call the code like this:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string finalResult = await PrintContent(@"C:\Users\name\Desktop\LotsOfLines.txt");
            textBox1.Text = finalResult;
        }
```

It works perfectly and finalResult variable has the right value however it takes around 3 seconds to read and my thread locks.
What did I do wrong so my thread is blocking?

Comment: Unrelated: `sr.Dispose();` is not needed. That's what `using ... ` is for.

Comment: Your thread "locks" or "blocks"? And how do you determine that?

Comment: @Fildor thanks for the Dipose part, I thought it's manual, well my UI freezes until the finalResult variable has gotten it's value, so I can't move the UI or resize as well

Comment: @MarcGravell _"C:\Users\name\Desktop\..."_ - so I guess there is no Http involved here.

Comment: @Fildor fair enough, ta

Comment: Have you tried using Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke ?

Comment: @Fildor Yes, I'm using StreamReader to read a local text file, get the returned string, and assign it to textBox1.Text, it takes around 2-3 seconds, it's a bit larger file.

Comment: @EpicDev how big is this file? if it is huge, then that might be an expensive UI operation; you *might* want to try `return File.ReadAllTextAsync(URL)`, to see if that works better, but...

Comment: I am not sure if there isn't something in Marc's suspicion about the StreamReader ... I personally would expect your code to be fine... and yes I'd try File.ReadAllTextAsync, too.

Comment: (for context, @Fildor is talking about a now-deleted comment where I mused that a lot of types that had async shoehorned in "late", make use of async-over-sync, especially when running on .NET Framework and/or where they aren't 100% happy that they can safely switch to true async paths; which is why I suggested `File.ReadAllTextAsync` - it is so specific that it doesn't have much visible behaviour to respect for compat, except "I got the data")

Comment: I suspect that `textBox1.Text = finalResult;` blocks your UI. Try to replace `await PrintContent(...` with `await Task.Delay(60 * 1000)`, set a plain string (same length as your file) onto your `TextBox` and see if it blocks for a minute or still 3 seconds.

Comment: @MarcGravell Sure, i'll try the File Class too, however my main point here is to understand why is the async operation still freezing the UI thread, I expected the control to be given back to the caller, also, I can use backgroundWorker or a new Thread but I'm learning async so I'll stick to that

Comment: @EpicDev first step is to rule out whether the pain point is updating the UI; you could just comment out the `textBox1.Text = finalResult;` line - if it no longer blocks, then the problem is the UI update step, not the data read step